# How to mock $cookiestore.put in AngularJS/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test my Authentication.Login service function.

In this service is call of another service and a cookiestore.put method.

I want to mock both function. But Im still get a error :/

I have try it with the spyon Function in Jasmine, but it doesnt work :

```
spyOn('base64', 'encode').and.returnValue(username + ';' + password);
spyOn('cookie', 'put').and.returnValue(username);
```

Can anybody help me ?

this is the authentication service :

```
function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $q) {
        //initialize service
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password) {
            //initialize promise object for asynchron behavior of the data 
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            //put login data in global variable to access in the root scope
            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            //put base64 data in header
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
            //put login data in cookie to keep user logged in, if he refresh the page
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override service using `$provide`:

```
var cookieStoreMock = {
  put: function() {
    return username;
  }
}

module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('$cookieStore', cookieStoreMock);
});

describe(...
```

Comment: thank you ! i will try it tomorrow and inform you :)